# Entity Framework SaveChanges not updating db

Tags: .net, entity-framework

Using sql server profiler I can see that the initial query for AnswerComment is going to the db but when I get to the ef.SaveChanges() nothing is getting to the db.  I'm using sqlexpress 2008 R2.

```
using (TPRDEntities ef = new TPRDEntities())
{
    var ac = ef.AnswerComments.Where(a => a.AnswerCommentID == answercomment.AnswerCommentID).FirstOrDefault();

    if (ac == null)
    {
        ac = new AnswerComment();
        ac.AnswerID = answercomment.AnswerID;
        ac.DisplayText = answercomment.DisplayText;
        ac.InsertDate = answercomment.InsertDate;
        ac.InsertUser = "save test user";
        ef.SaveChanges();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The new instance you create

```
ac = new AnswerComment();
```

is not known to EF.  It is a brand-new object instance that EF has not seen before.

You will have to add it to ef.AnswerComments

```
ef.AnswerComments.Insert(ac);
```

Also, ensure that ChangeTracking is active for `ef`.

Comment: Wow a downvote to an accepted answer one year later with no comment and no better answer.

Comment: The downvote is from me, i did a mistake... I cannot undo it until the answer is edited, sorry...

Comment: @schglurps: I have edited the answer.  Thank you for correcting the accidental downvote.

Answer (score 1):

I think you miss to add the `AnswerComment` to the Context, you've to do:

```
ac = new AnswerComment();
ac.AnswerID = answercomment.AnswerID;
ac.DisplayText = answercomment.DisplayText;
ac.InsertDate = answercomment.InsertDate;
ac.InsertUser = "save test user";

ef.AnswerComments.Add(ac);
ef.SaveChanges();
```

Answer (score 0):

You are never inserting the new item into the table:

```
ef.AnswerComments.Insert(ac);
ef.SaveChanges();
```